# DVD burning API for Java

Tags: java, api, dvd, dvd-burning

I'm looking for an API in Java to burn DVDs. I can't find anything on Google, so maybe I'm more lucky here... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much out there for java but I would look into [IMAPI2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with JNI.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think a wrapper already exists...